# Parsing String: Input string was not in a correct format. #

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, parsing, int

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that is requiring an int to work correctly. I pull an "ID" from a datagrid and then am trying to parse the int to allow the procedure to run, but am getting the error mentioned in the title. Any thoughts on a better way to do this?

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" Visible="true"></asp:BoundColumn>

<asp:Button ID="btnMarkComplete" Text="Mark Complete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<$# Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="BtnMarkCompleteClick"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>


int iD = Convert.ToInt32(d.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Comment: What is the value you're trying to convert?

Comment: Your string was not in the correct format, meaning, if was something like `abcde`, thus, could not be interpreted as an int.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and try seeing what value are you getting in "d.CommandArgument" ?

Comment: Why don't you just simply debug your code?

Comment: What does `d.CommandArgument.ToString()` return, it is obviosly not a valid int.

Comment: you need to show all relevant code.. what you have shown is really not very helpful in my opinion also look at your format here it's incorrect `CommandArgument='<$# Eval("ID") %>'` should replace `$#` with `<%=` [DataBinder.Eval Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) start reading here

Comment: You're getting the error because you're trying to convert the string <$# Eval("ID") %> to an int, that field won't bind due to the typo, the `$` should be a `%`

Comment: @DJKRAZE correct about the `$` but not about the `#`, the hash is correct for databinding, explained in the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question, "is there a better way to do this"?

Yes, and it's called `TryParse`:

```
int iD = 0;

if(Int32.TryParse(d.CommandArgument.ToString(), out iD))
{
   // Do something with iD
}
```

**Explanation**

You're implying (using a basic `Convert` method) that the input *can* be converted to an `Int32`, which is why you get an exception when it can't. With the way I've suggested above, you're simply trying to parse it. `TryParse` returns a `boolean` you can then evaluate to decide on a path of execution.

Comment: Well, this will make sure there's a check in place - but it won't affect the input you're passing it (i.e. the conversion still isn't happening). Be aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo there to start:

```
<$# Eval("ID") %>
```

Should be

```
<%# Eval("ID") %>
```

So you are trying to convert the string value `<$# Eval("ID") %>` to an integer which will fail and throw the error you are receiving. The field won't bind to ID because of the typo.