# Input string was not in a correct format using command argument in button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here i tried to update download count by one i.e dwncount column in db on clicking the button btndownloadpost. On clicking the button it shows

> "Input string was not in a correct format" error in line int countid =
>   Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());.

The countid and dwncount columns in db is of int datatype.
Below is the full code i used.

Button is like below

```
<div>
<asp:Button ID="btndownloadpost" CommandName="download" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("countid") %>' CssClass="btn btn-info" runat="server" Text="Download " OnCommand="btndownloadpost_Command" />
</div>
```

Code Behind the button

```
 protected void btndownloadpost_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName== "download")
    {
        int countid = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        int i = c.updatedwncount(countid, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["click"]));
        if (i > 0)
        {

            if (ViewState["click"] != null)
            {
                count = (int)ViewState["click"] + 1;
            }
            ViewState["click"] = count;
            Label18.Text = "Updated ";
        }


    }
}
```

Method used

```
 public int updatedwncount(int countid, int dwncount)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "update tbltry set dwncount=dwncount+1 where countid=@countid";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwncount", dwncount);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countid", countid);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: is button control is inside gridview ?

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32:

```
int countid;
int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out countid);
```

The Convert.Int32 method will emit exception if the Eval expression implies the input cannot be converted into `int`. In the other hand, TryParse will return `boolean` value, which can be evaluated on next execution plan.

Reference: [Parsing String: Input string was not in a correct format. #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319267/parsing-string-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: i'm trying but it not working ,may be i'm not doing it in a write way so can you help how to use it in may case as code is given.Your kind help will worth a lot to me.Thank you

Comment: Could you change Eval statement to something like <%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("countid").ToString()) ? 0 : Eval("countid")) %> ? This will emit zero in place of null, thus Convert or TryParse method will set the default value as 0 if the file has no download count.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `countid` is null. So check for Null value then parse it to int.

```
int countid = String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```